# Need batch file to count the number of files in subdirectories

Tags: batch-file

I want a batch file to count the files in sub directories. and save this count to text file.

here is outline what i exactly want:

One folder contain number of folders, so i need to take all the sub-folders file count to text file.

O/p will be:

folder1: 23

folder2: 34

folder3: 12

I think you got my point. please help me.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a slightly different method.

The below script iterates over subdirectories of the specified directory, calls `DIR /A-D` for each of them and extracts the file count from the summary of the `DIR`'s output to display it along with the name of the subdirectory.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "rootpath=%~1"
FOR /D %%D IN ("%rootpath%\*") DO (
  FOR /F %%K IN ('DIR /A-D "%%D" 2^>NUL ^| FIND "File(s)" ^|^| ECHO 0') DO (
    ECHO %%D: %%K
  )
)
```

The path to the parent directory is supposed to come from the command line.

The script only counts files located immediately in the subdirectories. However, it can easily be extended to return the counts of all files stored in the subdirectory trees, if necessary. Here's one way:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "rootpath=%~1"
FOR /D %%D IN ("%rootpath%\*") DO (
  SET cnt=0
  FOR /F %%K IN ('DIR /A-D /S "%%D" 2^>NUL ^| FIND "File(s)" ^|^| ECHO 0') DO (
    SET /A cnt+=%%K
  )
  SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
  ECHO %%D: !cnt!
  ENDLOCAL
)
```

The modified version works almost the same as the original one, except the output of `DIR` may now contain multiple summaries. The script extracts the file count from every summary and adds up all the counts to get the total file count in the directory tree. When displaying the results, delayed expansion needs to be enabled in this case, because the total count is being stored in an environment variable (`cnt`), and environment variables are not evaluated correctly in such cases using "normal" (immediate) expansion.

One other note is that both versions display include the paths when displaying the subdirectory names. If you want names only (as you seem to do based on one of your comments to the other answer), use `ECHO %%~nxD: ...` instead of `ECHO %%D: ...`.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

I've reworked this.  The example uses two batch files; `test.cmd` and `filecount.cmd`

`test.cmd` iterates directories only, and calls `filecount.cmd` for each one.

You only explicitly run the `test.cmd` file, which in turn calls `filecount.cmd` to count the files, and produces output that looks like the following, which is actual output from my short test just now.  If you do not want the count of the files in the main directory, just omit that line from the first batch file.

```
.: 7
folder1: 3
folder2: 2
folder3: 5
```

The example assumes the batch files are just in the same directory that you're counting files in.

test.cmd :

```
@echo off
setlocal

call filecount .

for /f %%f in ( 'dir /AD /b' ) do (
    call filecount %%f
)

:EOF
endlocal
```

filecount.cmd :

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set /a i=0

for /f %%f in ( 'dir /b /A-D %1' ) do (
    set /a i=i+1
    @rem echo %%f !i!
)

echo %1: %i%

:EOF
endlocal
```

`filecount.cmd` just echoes to the screen, so you can redirect that output to a file if you want to.

This is a rough-and-ready example, and cannot recursively crawl a directory structure as it sits, but you may be able to mangle it a little bit to accomplish that.  As I said in my original (pre-edit) answer, at some point the batch language just doesn't give you enough power (probably) and you'll need to look at something like vbscript or javascript.

Comment: Thanks for you reply,

@echo off 

set curr=%CD%

setLocal enableDELAYedeXpansion

for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('dir/s/b/ad') do (

pushd "%%a"

set N=0

for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%f in ('dir/b/a-d 2^>nul') do (

set /a N+=1

)

if !N! neq 0 (

echo %%a: !N! pics >> "!curr!\count.txt"

)

)

Output:

E:\test\folder1: N files

E:\test\folder1: N files

E:\test\folder1: N files



But I want this:

folder1: N files

folder2: N files

folder3: N files

Comment: @echo off 



set curr=%CD%



setLocal enableDELAYedeXpansion



for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('dir/s/b/ad') do (



pushd "%%a"


set N=0


for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%f in ('dir/b/a-d 2^>nul') do (


set /a N+=1


)


if !N! neq 0 (


echo %%a: !N! pics >> "!curr!\count.txt"


)


)


Output:


E:\test\folder1: N files


E:\test\folder1: N files


E:\test\folder1: N files



But I want this:


folder1: N files


folder2: N files


folder3: N files

Comment: Give me one moment and I'll post an update.  :-)

Comment: if i want the only folder names in the text file with count, but in above code which i have pasted. Giving absolute path.